# files list for package 'patch' is not a regular file

Tags: apt, dpkg, error-handling

```
Linux av-projects 3.11.0-14-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 17:04:55 UTC 2013 
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 14.10
```

I had a strange boot yesterday with some files little corrupt. I could repair most of it but I can't install and remove software with apt-get or dpkg. I get always this error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
files list for package 'patch' is not a regular file
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

it complains at the moment upgrading Virtualbox but it applies to any install, upgrade or remove.

Can somebody help me? I have read most of what is online to this error message but could so far not resolve this issue.

I have done already the common things like `apt-get update`, `upgrade`, `dpkg --configure -a`

This is the full output.

```
root@xxxxxx:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  virtualbox-4.2
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/64.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 828 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-4.2.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list for package 'patch' is not a regular file
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: paste the complete error log..after using apt-get update??

Comment: Please, the complete output is most useful.

Answer (score 2):

try -

1. Go into the /var/lib/dpkg directory
2. Make a backup of the "status" file
3. Open the status file as root and find the package that causes the error.
4. Delete all the text until the next PACKAGE: declaration in the file.

or you can use terminal to edit the status file as shown below but make a copy of that file before editing  -

```
sudo edit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

If you could attach the complete error then only we can give you the direct and clear error, even we will do the same , but we can mention the line that has to be omitted.

hope it helped you.

Comment: I've probably missed something, but how do you know it is Inkscape? It just mentions `patch` in the error.

Comment: @minerz029 mentioned that as just an example, as "be happy" did not attached the complete log, and yeah I got the similar question . that’s y.

Comment: I have tried that but without success. I deleted the entries mentioning virtualbox and it looks like it is not installed anymore but when I run an upgrade or remove I get the same error message

Comment: I also tried to do the same with package "patch" but then it complains about package "libpocketsphinx1" and so one.

Comment: will you please attach the complete error to your question..

Comment: dear Sushant,I don't understand your request. I added the full error message above. Did you see this? IF this is not the full message please tell me what additional infos do you require.
Thanks for your help and interest :)

Comment: check this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1232143

Comment: i think you have removed wrong line.. delete the new status file and use old one , then check the error suppose if it will say like "

    dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:

    reading files list for package 'inkscape': Input/output error

    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
" then in this case Open the status file as root and find the package that causes the error. In this case, its "PACKAGE: inkscape".

Comment: Thanks! this helped me fix my similar problem (re. `sane-utils` when trying to install virtualbox)

Comment: @benschwartz I have never used VB for ubuntu. glad to know, it helped you.